# Trying to unwrap double from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, double, nsuserdefaults, unwrap

It's been a while since I have done any Swift programming and it seems that since I last messed around with NSUserDefaults, some things have changed.

I have always have problems with unwrapping and since these changes have been made, I am finding it even more confusing. I am simply trying to set a variable to be a double that I have stored in group NSUserDefaults. This is my code:

```
    percent = defaults?.doubleForKey("percentage")
```

I've tried a few things such as:

```
    percent = defaults?.doubleForKey("percentage") as Double
```

However I can't seem to find the solution. It just states that the value is not unwrapped at the moment. Any help?

Comment: How are you setting defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaults` is an optional, so any expression using it will result in an optional.
Just unwrap it in an optional binding:

```
if let defaults = defaults {
    percent = defaults.doubleForKey("percentage")
}
```

or if you are 110% sure that `defaults` will never be nil (or you want the app to crash if it is nil), just use forced unwrapping by replacing `?` with `!`:

```
percent = defaults!.doubleForKey("percentage")
```